# Mutable version of apply?

Tags: r, dataframe

I am trying to get an average value for each subset in dataframe, and incorporate that info into a column.

I can do that with lapply, but I can't make it "stick". Is there a variant of the apply family of functions with side effects? Anything in plyr library would be fine too.

```
data <- data.frame(
  A = sample(LETTERS[1:3], 20, replace=TRUE),
  B = runif(20),
  C = LETTERS[1:20])
# split by A
dataByA <- split(data, factor(data$A))
# get average of B per set
lapply(dataByA, function(df) {df$Bmean <- mean(df$B)}) # does nothing!
# remerge subsets
data <- rbind.fill(dataByA)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This may work:

```
library(plyr)
data1<-ddply(data,.(A),transform,Bmean=mean(B))


head(data1)
 A           B C    Bmean
1  A 0.616156407 E 0.5492000
2  A 0.568187293 G 0.5492000
3  A 0.899395311 H 0.5492000
4  A 0.113060973 K 0.5492000
5  B 0.872838203 A 0.7885643
6  B 0.906216467 B 0.7885643
7  B 0.944196701 N 0.7885643
8  B 0.445983319 O 0.7885643
9  B 0.773586589 T 0.7885643
```

Comment: Perfect. I wasn't familiar with the transform functions. Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

Try this:

```
data$Bmean <- ave(data$B, data$A)
```

Answer (score 5):

There are many options for this sort of thing, but to correct your immediate mistake, your anonymous function in `lapply` simply isn't returning anything. Just make it return the piece it's operating on:

```
{df$Bmean <- mean(df$B); df}
```

I will leave it to the masses to show you your options using `by`, `ddply` + `mutate` or `transform` and `data.table`.

Answer (score 2):

As per @joran, I will be one of the masses ;) 
The solution in data.table is as follows

```
DT[ , Bmean := mean(B), by=A]
```

---

Where `DT` is simply

```
library(data.table)
DT <- data.table( <your data frame> )
```

Comment: @G.Grothendieck, thanks got pointing that out.  Fixed the answer.